# Jira Test Automation Using Selenium WebAPI

Tags: java, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, jira

We recorded a test case to log into jira using Selenium IDE. And it was running correctly.BUT when it exported to java web driver(jUnit4), it did not worked and gave element not found error.

The code is :

```
package newjiralogin;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;


public class NewJiraLogin {

  private WebDriver driver;

  private String baseUrl;

  private final StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();


  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    baseUrl = "http://jiratest/";

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testUntitled2() throws Exception {

    driver.get("http://jiratest");

    driver.findElement(By.id("login-form-username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-form-username")).sendKeys("saumlk");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-form-password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-form-password")).sendKeys("saumlk");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }
```

The main Method class :

```
package newjiralogin;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;


public class NewJiralogintest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {                    
       JUnitCore.main("newjiralogin.NewJiraLogin");  
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please paste the error u are getting and also at which line u are seeing element not found error... Moreover do check the locators in ur webpage and make sure if they are correct

Comment: Just to confirm and to avoid all of us wasting our time here; are you automating Jira to perform QA on Jira such as testing a plugin, or are you automating Jira to replace a manual task carried out by a person?  If it is the latter, then you should look at using the Jira API rather than selenium. This would be faster and more stable

Comment: Anuragh27crony 

This is the error that I got.

"org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException". 

and it was occurred after this line. 
driver.findElement(By.id("login-form-username")).clear();

Answer (score 1):

The login form resides inside an iframe, i.e. before accessing the elements you have to switch the context of the driver, .e.g.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("gadget-0");
```

(assuming "gadget-0" is the id of the frame which contains the login box).

I'm not an expert for the IDE->WebDriver conversion, but it seems that the context switch got lost. If you want to implement UI automation for JIRA, have a look at the JIRA PageObjects which really ease many of the common tasks. A sample how they can be employed is available at the Atlassian documentation pages or here: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/07/part-3-agile-testing-jira-plugins-system-tests/. This blog entry is part of a short series we wrote b/c we had similar issues and wanted to share what we learned.